# Post JSON with R

Tags: json, r, http, post

I have the following body:

```
{
 "engine": "Google",
"data": {
 "text": "Hello, world",
 "voice": "en-US"
 }
}
```

which the Content-Type header should be application/json and make the request with body as above. How I use the POST function in R? I should receive a response type:

```
{
"success": true,
"id": "<RFC4122 uuid>"
}
```

I want to request that last info on this website "soundoftext.com"

I've tried this using the httr package:

```
url <- "http://soundoftext.com/"
requestBody <- paste0('
{"engine" : "Google",
"data" : [{"text" : "Hello, world", 
      "voice" : "en-US"]}}')

 res <- httr::POST(url = url,
           body = requestBody,
           encode = "json")
```

But I cannot get the information detailed in the response. I get this raw data (UTF-8 encoded) at the content.

3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20 68 74 6d 6c 3e 3c 68 74 6d 6c 20 6c 61 6e 67 3d 22 65 6e 22 3e 3c 68 65 61 64 3e 3c 6d 65 74 61 20 63 68 61 72 73 65 74 3d 22 75 74 66 2d 38 22 3e 3c 6d 65 74 61 20 6e 61 6d 65 3d 22 76 69 65 77 70 6f 72 74 22 20 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 3d 22 77 69 64 74 68 3d 64 65 76 69 63 65 2d 77 69 64 74 68 2c 69 6e 69 74 69 61 6c 2d 73 63 61 6c 65 3d 31 2c 73 68 72 69 6e 6b 2d 74 6f 2d 66 69 74 3d 6e 6f 22 3e 3c 6d 65 74 61 20 6e 61 6d 65 3d 22 74 68 65 6d 65 2d 63 6f 6c 6f 72 22 20 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 3d 22 23 30 30 30 30 30 30 22 3e 3c 6c 69 6e 6b 20 72 65 6c 3d 22 6d 61 6e 69 66 65 73 74 22 20 68 72 65 66 3d 22 2f 6d 61 6e 69 66 65 73 74 2e 6a 73 6f 6e 22 3e 3c 6c 69 6e 6b 20 72 65 6c 3d 22 73 68 6f 72 74 63 75 74 20 69 63 6f 6e 22 20 68 72 65 66 3d 22 2f 66 61 76 69 63 6f 6e 2e 69 63 6f 22 3e 3c 6c 69 6e 6b 20 68 72 65 66 3d 22 68 74 74 70 73 3a 2f 2f 66 6f 6e 74 73 2e 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 61 70 69 73 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 63 73 73 3f 66 61 6d 69 6c 79 3d 4f 70 65 6e 2b 53 61 6e 73 3a 34 30 30 2c 36 30 30 2c 37 30 30 22 20 72 65 6c 3d 22 73 74 79 6c 65 73 68 65 65 74 22 3e 3c 73 63 72 69 70 74 20 73 72 63 3d 22 68 74 74 70 73 3a 2f 2f 63 68 65 63 6b 6f 75 74 2e 73 74 72 69 70 65 2e 63 6f 6d 2f 63 68 65 63 6b 6f 75 74 2e 6a 73 22 3e 3c 2f 73 63 72 69 70 74 3e 3c 74 69 74 6c 65 3e 53 6f 75 6e 64 20 6f 66 20 54 65 78 74 3c 2f 74 69 74 6c 65 3e 3c 6c 69 6e 6b 20 68 72 65 66 3d 22 2f 73 74 61 74 69 63 2f 63 73 73 2f 6d 61 69 6e 2e 31 34 39 38 65 66 36 34 2e 63 73 73 22 20 72 65 6c 3d 22 73 74 79 6c 65 73 68 65 65 74 22 3e 3c 2f 68 65 61 64 3e 3c 62 6f 64 79 3e 3c 6e 6f 73 63 72 69 70 74 3e 59 6f 75 20 6e 65 65 64 20 74 6f 20 65 6e 61 62 6c 65 20 4a 61 76 61 53 63 72 69 70 74 20 74 6f 20 72 75 6e 20 74 68 69 73 20 61 70 70 2e 3c 2f 6e 6f 73 63 72 69 70 74 3e 3c 64 69 76 20 69 64 3d 22 72 6f 6f 74 22 3e 3c 2f 64 69 76 3e 3c 73 63 72 69 70 74 20 74 79 70 65 3d 22 74 65 78 74 2f 6a 61 76 61 73 63 72 69 70 74 22 20 73 72 63 3d 22 2f 73 74 61 74 69 63 2f 6a 73 2f 6d 61 69 6e 2e 37 66 32 30 38 38 64 33 2e 6a 73 22 3e 3c 2f 73 63 72 69 70 74 3e 3c 2f 62 6f 64 79 3e 3c 2f 68 74 6d 6c 3e

Is the information located in this raw data?

Comment: I can't duplicate your results, but have you tried `content(res, as="text") %>% fromJSON()` to decode the data?  You might also writeBin the data to a file then read it as text...

Answer (score 0):

Owner of Sound of Text here.

It looks like you are posting to the wrong URL.
You should send your POST request to "https://api.soundoftext.com/sounds".

Try this and let me know the result. I am not familiar with R, but I will do my best to help.

You can see the full documentation for the API here: https://soundoftext.com/docs

Comment: Thank you  @ncpierson. I got a bad request with this code. url <- "https://soundoftext.com/api/sounds"
requestBody <- toJSON(list(paste0('
                      {"engine" : "Google",
                      "data" : [{"text" : "Hello, world", 
                      "voice" : "en-US"]}}')))

res <- httr::POST(url = url,
                  httr::add_headers('Content-Type' = 'application/json'),
                  httr::add_headers('Accept' = 'application/json'),
                  body = requestBody,
                  encode = "json")

Comment: It looks like your "data" value is an array? It should be a plain JSON Object. LIke this:  { "engine" : "Google", "data" : { "text" : "Hello, world", "voice" : "en-US" } }